Error 500.19 when Deploying Blazor Project to IIS – Configuration Page Invalid
I'm trying to deploy my Blazor Project on IIS but error 500.19 keep coming. It stated that the configuration page is invalid. I checked the web.config file but nothing is wrong there.

This is my web_config file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="" verb="" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\BlazorApp2.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 6316b5ad-9de8-40a7-aa37-adbff4002c90-->

I thought maybe there's something wrong with permission with publish folder. But I've confirmed that the permission for IIS_IUSRS is granted.

does anyone know what might be missing here?

You forgot to install ASP.NET Core module. Read the linked thread to learn more.
